# Select main Crystal Report data according to parameter

Tags: .net, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I have a Crystal Report in Visual Studio 2010 and I want to select data from a table.

In Database Fields I have only the table I wish to view.

If I pass in a single-parameter primary key value into the report in a Parameter field (i.e. a serial value), how can I make the Crystal Report only show the data that corresponds to the single row which is referred to by that parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set up a selection formula - try:

- From the toolbar, press the [image] button (or select Report > Selection Formulas > Record... from the menus).
- In the Choose Field dialog, double-click on the dataset field you want to select.
- In the Select Expert dialog, click the Show Formula button and enter a condition like this:
  `{Table.Field} = {?Parameter}` . (Use the appropriate table, field and parameter names.)
- Click OK in the Select Expert dialog.

Your report should now select by parameter value.